# Is the non-generic getClass() method of constant-specific class bodies by design or an oversight of Java?

Tags: java, generics, enums

The following code has comments indicating two similar lines, one of which compiles, and one of which does not.

```
public class TestGenericCollections extends TestCase {
  List<Key<? extends Enum<?>>> keyList;

  public TestGenericCollections() {
    keyList = Lists.newArrayList();
  }

  public <T extends Enum<T>> void  addEnum(List<T> values) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(values.size() > 0);
    // Signature of Key.get():
    //  public static <T> Key<T> get(Class<T> type)

    // the following line compiles without warning or error
    keyList.add(Key.get(values.get(0).getDeclaringClass()));
    // The following line fails to compile with this error message in Eclipse:
    //   The method add(Key<? extends Enum<?>>) in the type List<Key<? extends Enum<?>>> 
    //   is not applicable for the arguments (Key<capture#1-of ? extends Enum>)
    keyList.add(Key.get(values.get(0).getClass()));
  }
```

The error message is very interesting.  Note that there is no `Enum<?>`, it is a raw `Enum`.  That means that any generic methods/collections/etc. that would want to operate on the anonymous constant-specific class body types of enums have to forgo generics and use the annotation @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") if they want to avoid compiler warnings.  That's why that line won't compile but the one above it will.  `Enum<T>.GetDeclaringClass()` properly returns a generic type, but the compiler-created anonymous constant-specific classes for each `Enum` value constant do not.

So, what's the rationale?  Is this an oversight or is there a reason the language designers didn't change the signature on anonymous constant-specific class bodies of `Enum`'s `getClass()` methods to be generic like they did for `Object.getClass()` when Java generics were added to the language?

Comment: It's part of Guice, but it doesn't matter for the purpose of this.  You can imagine the collection type to be List<Class<? extends Enum<?>>> and you'll get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you suggest can be useful. However I wouldn't call it an oversight.

The signature of `getClass()` is specifically defined in the language spec, and requires special compiler handling.

To get what you want, language spec needs another exception for enums. The additional rule wouldn't be simple. The use cases are probably not common enough to justify the cost.

--

If `getClass()` returns `Class<? extends X>` instead of `Class<? extends |X|>`, it would be a lot more useful in most use cases (like in your example). It's not theoretically correct, but practically it's safe in intuitive uses. We could define such a `getClass()` ourselves

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static public <T> Class<? extends T> getClass(T obj)
{
    return (Class<? extends T>)obj.getClass();
}


// compiles
keyList.add(Key.get(getClass(values.get(0))));
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains it and I see that this behavior isn't specific to enums, any generic type has this behavior.  I guess when I saw the signature of getClass() in the javadoc was that it returned a Class<?>, I assumed it operated intuitively and didn't dig into it.  Erasure bites again.

Answer (score 1):

The static return type of `Object.getClass()` is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `X` is the static type of the object. The `? extends` because the actual type of the object may be a subtype of its static type and the erasure `|X|`, because there's only one class object per generic declaration. Both of these restrictions do not apply to enums which are (1) final and (2) never generic. Thus it is sound for `getDeclaringClass()` to have the static return type `Class<X>`. `getClass()` is not overridden *anywhere* by *any* class because it's `final`.

(I *think* this answers your question.)